# Not able to read £1,000.00 from excel using poi

Tags: apache-poi

I know how read a number, a string etc but now aware of reading an alphanumeric or special characters. Currently i am trying to read/write £1,000.00 to excel using apache poi but i got format exception. Can you please give me some lines of code for it.

Below is the code:

```
    String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText().trim().replaceAll("\\D", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    env.setInputFile(new FileInputStream("C://ABC//DataNew.xls"));
    env.setBook(new HSSFWorkbook(env.getInputFile()));
    env.setOutFile(new FileOutputStream("C://ABC//DataNew.xls"));
    env.getBook().createSheet("test").createRow(15).createCell((short)6).setCellValue(str);
    env.getBook().write(env.getOutFile());
    env.getOutFile().flush();
    env.getOutFile().close();
```

And the error I am getting is :

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFormatException: Unable to construct record instance, the following exception occured: null
```

Comment: In Excel, £1,000.00 would normally be stored simply as the number 1000, with UK currency format applied.

Comment: so should I enter only 1000 removing everything else??

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the latest (3.11 beta 1 as of writing), did you try upgrading?

Comment: Yes i got it solved. It was due to the old version of poi. I was using 2.5 but now using 3.8 beta